# Can we combine php and jsp?

Tags: php, html, jsp

If I use a web page ie. HTML page and write some php code in it. Also, if I write some jsp code in it and save the file as .jsp, can this be done? Just a usual question strike my mind. So, wanted to ask you all. Sorry, if I sound funny. I have knowledge of html and jsp. But a newbie to php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are different technologies and run on different servers. Why do you need that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. Each is processed by a separate runtime and they do not interoperate.

Answer (score 1):

Not in any sensible fashion. PHP and JSP are both server-side scripting languages, but they are typically used in very different environments, and are not compatible. It doesn't make sense to try and combine them - pick one and use it.